# Case-insensitive match with Boost Xpressive

Tags: c++, boost, boost-xpressive

I just can't get the `regex_match` function to find case-insensitive matches. Even though `boost::xpressive::regex_constants::icase` is [defined](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/xpressive/regex_constants.hpp) and I use a cast (so there is no ambiguity to the `icase` method of Xpressive), I get a compilation error (VS2010):

> error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const boost::xpressive::detail::modifier_op' to 'boost::xpressive::regex_constants::match_flag_type'

Some code to reproduce:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive.hpp>

int main(){
    std::string str("FOO");
    boost::xpressive::sregex re = boost::xpressive::sregex_compiler().compile("foo");
    bool result = regex_match(str,re,(boost::xpressive::regex_constants::match_flag_type)boost::xpressive::regex_constants::icase);
    if(result){
        std::cout << "Match!";
    }else{
        std::cout << "No match!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do you know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
boost::xpressive::sregex re = boost::xpressive::sregex_compiler().
compile("foo", boost::xpressive::icase);
```

`syntax_options_type` (that is `boost::xpressive::regex_constants::icase_`) is not `match_flag_type` (3 argument for `regex_match` should have this type).

Comment: Right. And in the future, listen to what the compiler tells you. The fact that you had to cast the `icase` flag to `match_flag_type` to get it compile should have tipped you off that you were doing something wrong. And then read the docs. :-)